# Check if in Array there are values different from than 0000-00-00

Tags: php, arrays

I'm triyng to know if in array below there are values differents from 0000-00-00

```
$periods = array("0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00");
```

I'm expect:

```
$periods = array("0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "2017-00-00");
TRUE

$periods = array("0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00", "0000-00-00");
FALSE
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_unique to check if the array only have one element "0000-00-00"

```
echo array_unique($periods) == ["0000-00-00"];
```

or

```
$periods_flip = array_flip($periods);
echo isset($periods_flip["0000-00-00"]) && (count($periods_flip) == 1);
```